# preferred order of columns in the key

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like so:

```
table T ( account_id bigint, event_date datetime ... );
```

and later make queries like so:

```
select ...
from T
where account_id = 'ABC'
  and event_date >= '2016-01-01'
```

Does the order of columns in the index matter, ie:

```
key (`account_id`, `event_date`)
```

Or

```
key (`event_date`, `account_id`)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building an index for `a = constant AND b >= ...`, put any and all '=' columns first; end with one 'range': `INDEX(a, b)`.  In your case `INDEX(account_id, event_date)`.

You *do* need a `PRIMARY KEY` on your table, but it is unclear whether this is suitable.  The PK *must* be unique.

For more discussion, see [*my cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/). The info is the same for MySQL as for MariaDB.  If you prefer, see [MySQL: Building the best INDEX for a given SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: When I tried both ways your recommended approach yielded significantly better result in terms execution time and DESCRIBE reported row count.